# TikZ - why are thicknesses of lines hardcoded into the styles for calling the /tikz/line width - key?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

When drawing objects with TikZ, e.g., rectangles, then for obtaining the actual width of these objects, the thickness of lines needs to be taken into account.

This is exhibited by the following example where you can see that the width of the rectangle-object also depends on the thickness of lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/my thick thickness/.initial=5mm,
  /tikz/my thick/.style={/tikz/line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness}},
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red, my thick] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\noindent\leaders\hrule\hskip\dimexpr 
2cm+ \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness}\relax \space these are 2cm + thickness
of rules of the rectangle.

\noindent\leaders\hrule\hskip2cm \space these are 2cm.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

E.g., assume, you want two rectangles.
If you just do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/my thick thickness/.initial=5mm,
  /tikz/my thick/.style={/tikz/line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness}},
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red, my thick] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
\draw[blue, my thick] (2cm,0) rectangle (4cm,2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\noindent\leaders\hrule\hskip\dimexpr 
2cm+ \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness}\relax \space these are 2cm + thickness
of rules of the rectangle.

\noindent\leaders\hrule\hskip2cm \space these are 2cm.

\end{document}
```

, then rules of the rectangles overlap:

[image]

In order to avoid this, you need to take thickness of lines into account:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/my thick thickness/.initial=5mm,
  /tikz/my thick/.style={/tikz/line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness}},
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red, my thick] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
\draw[blue, my thick] (2cm+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness},0) rectangle (4cm+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness},2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\noindent\leaders\hrule\hskip\dimexpr 
2cm+ \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness}\relax \space these are 2cm + thickness
of rules of the rectangle.

\noindent\leaders\hrule\hskip2cm \space these are 2cm.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

So you may need to have TeX do calculations where the values of thicknesses of lines/rules are taken into account.

But with TikZ you only have styles `/tikz/ultra thin`, `/tikz/very thin`, `/tikz/thin`, `/tikz/semithick`, `/tikz/thick`, `/tikz/very thick`, `/tikz/ultra thick` for calling the `/tikz/line width=`-key with a specific value.

But these styles do not allow you to access these values for doing calculations on them.

So my questions are:

1. Why are the line-thicknesses hard-coded into these styles instead of coming from value-keys as with the `my thick`-style introduced in my examples?
2. Am I overlooking something more or less subtle which makes accessing line-thicknesses for calculations obsolete?
3. Are there better ways of specifying location of the blue square so that the line making the right edge of the red square is not overlapped by the line making the left edge of the blue square?

Comment: 1. Because it was programmed that way many years ago. 2. The line thickness is accessibly in the dimen `\pgflinewidth`. 3. Either by using `\pgflinewidth` directly or by using nodes (see answer by DraUX) which also uses `\pgflinewidth` (or rather half of it) as the default value of the `outer sep`s. The node approach is preferable if you have to align objects with different linewidths. Otherwise it gets complicated.

Comment: Worse the thickness key defined is not scaled if you scale the tikzpicture.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Yes, because it's a [coordinate transformation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.3) (i.e. it transforms the coordinate system) and not a [canvas transformation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't answer you all your questions, but at least your last one. You can position the rectangles without any calculations by using the tikzlibrary `positioning`. Draw the rectangles as a `node` and give them names, so you can refer to them. By using the option `right = 0cm of rectangleA` the positioning is automatically calculated from the border of the node which is its outer end (including the line thicknes). Your code would look about like the following one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/my thick thickness/.initial=5mm,
  /tikz/my thick/.style={/tikz/line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness}},
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, red, my thick, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm] (rectA) at  (0,0) {};
\node[draw, blue, my thick, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm, right = 0cm of rectA] (rect) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\noindent\leaders\hrule\hskip\dimexpr 
2cm+ \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my thick thickness}\relax \space these are 2cm + thickness
of rules of the rectangle.

\noindent\leaders\hrule\hskip2cm \space these are 2cm.

\end{document}
```

[image]